# SS 2005 SP4 install giving vsJitDebugger events

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, eventviewer

Windows Server 2003, SQL Server 2005 (9.00.3080)

I installed SS2005 SP4 without a problem and immediately started getting vsJitDebugger 'unhandled win32 exception' messages in the application log every couple of minutes.  I changed the DEP to only essential programs (as suggested) but now I get the debugger popup.

I want to get rid of the 'unhandled win32 exception' messages completely as I don't know what caused them.  I read in some posts about using ccmclean.exe, that is was a bad uninstall of the client application, and a Management Point issue.

Can someone help me with this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this first because a problem when we went to version 8.8 of McAfee.

In case anyone runs into this you can use the following steps to unregister a dll if you are using McAfee version 8.8 (32 bit servers):

1. cd to c:\program files\common files\mcafee\systemcore
2. regsvr32.exe /u scriptsn.dll

Also keep in mind that most any patch sets DEP to 'all programs' and I reset it to only 'essential programs'